# Can I set text background to be blurry over an image?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to set the background of text blurry over an image? Like

```css
h1 { 
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: <blurry>; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <h1>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h1> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** most of the solution online show how to *blur* the image. What I am seeking for is something to apply a blur filter *just to the background of the text* element. I don't know if you can set this inside `h1` element or not.

Comment: Is this what you wanted? http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/yyOodm/

Answer (score 2):

In this example, I used an image as background for the blur effect to be more evident, but if you want to change the image by a color, simply replace the ***background-image*** attribute with ***background-color: # 000000;***

Note that # 000000 is your desired color in hex, so you should override this value.

```
<body> 
  <div class="background">
  </div>
  <h1 class="text"> The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h1> 
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.background { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG');
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.text {
position: relative;
z-index: 3; 
}
```

[Look at the example I made](https://jsfiddle.net/ocutowzp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add opacity

```
.element{
  opacity : 0.1;
}
```